# How to get all Dates between two Dates in Android Room

Tags: java, android, sql, android-room

i have an application in which the users do some tasks. if they finished the task, it will be safed in a room database with the startdate and enddate. start and enddate are stored with a typeconverter from date to long. then the users can choose two dates from a daterangepicker. When the selection is done, they can press a button and all activities with the dates between the startdate and enddate from the picker will be shown to the user in a recyclerview.

The problem is that the @Query statement in the DAO Class is not inclusive. If running it excludes the endate by one day.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE start_time BETWEEN :from AND :to")
List<TimeEntity> getChoosenTimes(long from, long to);
```

For example. If i want to pick all the days between 1. April and 30. April the user did some tasks, it gives me only all days up to 29. April.

Can anybody tell me how i can change the query to not exclude the last day?

Comment: Add one day to endday.

Comment: *...all activities with the dates between the startdate and enddate from the picker will be shown...* your query checks only the column `start_time` to be between `:from` and `:to`. It does not check the column `end_time`. Is this that you want?

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look, the daterangepicker could use dates that include the date and time down to milliseconds (long/Long) but at a guess uses the start of the day e.g. `2023-04-01 00:00:00.000` and `2023-04-30 00:00:00.000`.

- Note these are visual representations of the value not the actual value that is stored (e.g. `23-04-01 00:00:00.000` would be stored as `1680307200000`, whilst if not including milliseconds, `23-04-01 00:00:00`, then it would be stored as `1680307200`).

Thus virtually any date/time/millis on 04/30 will be excluded unless it is the very first milli second of the date which is highly unlikely.

- If the milliseconds are not returned and just the time, the difference would be that the selection would then only include those rows that had a date/time of up to and including `23-04-30 00:00:00` NOT `23-04-30 00:00:01` or greater.

This appears to match your description of the issue.

What you can do is just use the date part for the comparisons and the SQLite `date` function will do this *(if the milliseconds are dropped AND the function is told that it is handling a unix timestamp)*

- a) drop the milli seconds by dividing by 1000 and then
- b) use the date function to extract just the date component with the **unixepoch** modifier.

So you could use *(assuming that milliseconds are stored)*:-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE date(start_time / 1000,'unixepoch') BETWEEN date(:from/1000,'unixepoch') AND date(:to/1000,'unixepoch')")
```

You may wish to refer to https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

- Note the above is in-principle code, that is the code has not been compiled and/or run.
- if the milliseconds are not stored then simply remove the 3 divisions by 1000 e.g. `@Query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE date(start_time,'unixepoch') BETWEEN date(:from,'unixepoch') AND date(:to,'unixepoch')")`

> they can press a button and all activities with the dates between the startdate and enddate from the picker will be shown to the user in a recyclerview.

You are only showing rows that have the start date in the date range. It would not show, for example one that started on 31st march and ended on 10th April. For that, assuming that the end date/time is held in a column name **end_time** then you could use (assuming no milliseconds):-

`@Query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE date(start_time,'unixepoch') BETWEEN date(:from,'unixepoch') AND date(:to,'unixepoch') OR date(end_time,'unixepoch') BETWEEN date(:from,'unixepoch') AND date(:to,'unixepoch')")`

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this its work for me

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE start_time BETWEEN strftime('%s', date(:from/1000, " +
        "'unixepoch'))  AND strftime('%s', date(:to/1000, 'unixepoch')) )
List<TimeEntity> getChoosenTimes(long from, long to);
```